# Writing UI tests for RTL language

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-espresso

I am trying to write UI tests for RTL language. Here is a scenario. I have an AutoCompleteTextView, on which when I try to tag a user ("@user"), it shows dropdown of suggested users. This works for RTL & LTR languages when I manually type the strings.
However, if I try to test using espresso the functionality it doesn't work as expected.

Here is how I am trying to write UI test : 
Whenever I tell edit text to type “@u” using `onView(withId(R.id.message_input_field)).perform(typeText("@u"))`, Espresso generates key events to inject the characters into edit text. Something like, KEY_DOWN_SHIFT, KEY_DOWN_2, KEY_UP_SHIFT, KEY_UP_2, this types “@” and so on. Everything works fine for English language.
Problem occurs when we try to tag using RTL characters, using something like `onView(withId(R.id.message_input_field)).perform(typeText("@פ"))`. Espresso fails to recognize the RTL characters & can not generate key events, eventually throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get key events for string פ (i.e. current IME does not understand how to translate the string into key events)`
I tried to do `replaceText(…)` instead of `typeText(…)` but replaceText in turn does editText.setText(…). but it doesn’t show the drop down. Weird.

How do I write UI test for this scenario?

P.S. It doesn’t matter what is your device language or what is you currently selected keyboard is.